# User inputs data to tableview using a button

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I need to make a JavaFX program where the user inputs the names with a textfield and the speed with togglebuttons while using FXML to build the components .I've been working on this for several days now and have not had any luck.

```
<TableView fx:id="table" layoutX="200.0" prefHeight="420.0" prefWidth="461.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="firstn" prefWidth="75.0" text="First Name" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="lastn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Last Name" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="addresss" prefWidth="75.0" text="Address" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="speeed" prefWidth="84.0" text="Speed(mb/s)" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="bwidth" prefWidth="75.0" text="Bandwidth" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="durationn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Duration" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
      <TextField fx:id="fname" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="46.0" promptText="First Name" />
      <TextField fx:id="lname" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="71.0" promptText="Last Name" />
      <TextField fx:id="address" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="96.0" promptText="Address" />
      <Button layoutX="31.0" layoutY="339.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#save1" text="Save Package" />
<ToggleButton fx:id="sp1" layoutX="11.0" layoutY="169.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="2">
         <toggleGroup>
            <ToggleGroup fx:id="speed" />
         </toggleGroup>
      </ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton fx:id="sp2" layoutX="34.0" layoutY="169.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="5" toggleGroup="$speed" />
      <ToggleButton fx:id="sp3" layoutX="57.0" layoutY="169.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="10" toggleGroup="$speed" />
      <ToggleButton fx:id="sp4" layoutX="85.0" layoutY="169.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="20" toggleGroup="$speed" />
      <ToggleButton fx:id="sp5" layoutX="114.0" layoutY="169.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="50" toggleGroup="$speed" />
      <ToggleButton fx:id="sp6" layoutX="143.0" layoutY="169.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="100" toggleGroup="$speed" />
      <ToggleButton fx:id="ba1" layoutX="13.0" layoutY="237.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="1">
         <toggleGroup>
            <ToggleGroup fx:id="bandw" />
         </toggleGroup>
      </ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton fx:id="ba2" layoutX="37.0" layoutY="237.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="5" toggleGroup="$bandw" />
      <ToggleButton fx:id="ba3" layoutX="61.0" layoutY="237.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="10" toggleGroup="$bandw" />
      <ToggleButton fx:id="ba4" layoutX="89.0" layoutY="237.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="100" toggleGroup="$bandw" />
      <ToggleButton fx:id="ba5" layoutX="125.0" layoutY="237.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Flat" toggleGroup="$bandw" />
      <ToggleButton fx:id="du1" layoutX="13.0" layoutY="295.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="1 year">
         <toggleGroup>
            <ToggleGroup fx:id="duration" />
         </toggleGroup>
      </ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton fx:id="du2" layoutX="70.0" layoutY="295.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="2 years" toggleGroup="$duration" />
```

```
    @FXML
    private TextField fname;
    @FXML
    private TextField lname;
    @FXML
    private TextField address;
    @FXML
    private ToggleGroup speed;
    @FXML
    private ToggleGroup bandw;
    @FXML
    private ToggleGroup duration;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
public void save1(ActionEvent e){
        ObservableList<Person> data = table.getItems();
        data.add(new Person(fname.getText(),lname.getText(),address.getText(),
               speed.getSelectedToggle(),bandw.getSelectedToggle(),duration.getSelectedToggle()));
table.setItems(data);
    }
```

Basically, this is how my program should look like, but I can't get the save button to add to the tableview.

[image: inline screenshot]

Comment: *Never* set a variable initialized via `@FXML` to a `new` value.

Comment: Can you expand this to a [mre]?

Comment: To add to a `TableView`, just add a new object to the `List<Person>` that you have displayed within it. You should not need to call `table.setItems()` more than once. A simple `table.getItems().add(new Person())` should suffice. That being said, without a [mcve], it's impossible for us to determine what your issue is.

Comment: Unrelated: It's best to learn the Java naming conventions and stick to them. This would help you avoid using such confusing `fx:id` values as "speeed," "durationn," and "addresss," to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

You are already on the right track but there are few things you not doing right and missing as well. I will highlight some few points before posting the working code snippet.

1. `@FXML` is used to inject components defined in the `FXML` document into the controller. Hence, you should not assign new components to injected properties.
   Thus,

```
@FXML
    private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
```

should be changed to

```
@FXML
    private TableView<Person> table;
```

2. Since you defined the table columns in the `FXML` document, you need to inject them into the controller, though not recommended.
3. You need to configure the cell value factories for each of the table columns. This helps JavaFx to know which `Person` property belongs to which table column.
4. `speed.getSelectedToggle()` is returning a Toggle object, which may not be the behavior you want.

Below are a few of the classes I edited.

**`Controller class`**

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class TableViewController implements Initializable {
    @FXML private TextField fname;
    @FXML private TextField lname;
    @FXML private TextField address;
    @FXML private ToggleGroup speed;
    @FXML private ToggleGroup bandw;
    @FXML private ToggleGroup duration;

    //INject both table and column from the fxml file
    @FXML private TableView<Person> table;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Person,String> firstn;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Person,String> lastn;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Person,String> addresss;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Person,String> speeed;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Person,String> bwidth;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Person,String> durationn;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        //Configure which property of the Person object belongs to which table column by
        //setting cell value factor for each column
        firstn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("firstName"));
        lastn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("lastName"));
        addresss.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("address"));
        speeed.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("speed"));
        bwidth.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("bandWidth"));
        durationn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("duration"));
    }
    public void save1(ActionEvent e){
        //Get selected Toggle buttons
        ToggleButton selectedSpeed = (ToggleButton) speed.getSelectedToggle();
        ToggleButton selectedDuration = (ToggleButton) duration.getSelectedToggle();
        ToggleButton selectedBandwidth = (ToggleButton) bandw.getSelectedToggle();

        //Create a person from the input data
        Person person  = new Person(fname.getText(), lname.getText(), address.getText(),
                selectedSpeed.getText(), selectedBandwidth.getText(), selectedDuration.getText());

        //Add the person to the table data source
        table.getItems().add(person);
    }
}
```

**`Person class`**

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
    private String speed;
    private String bandWidth;
    private String duration;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String address, String speed, String bandWidth, String duration) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.bandWidth = bandWidth;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(String speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public String getBandWidth() {
        return bandWidth;
    }

    public void setBandWidth(String bandWidth) {
        this.bandWidth = bandWidth;
    }

    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to update your JavaFX knowledge. Controller classes do not need to implement interface `Initializable`, it just needs to define method `public void initialize()`. Refer to [Introduction to FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html) which is part of the Java documentation. Also, it is recommended not to use class `PropertyValueFactory` but simply to implement the `Callback` interface.

Comment: @Abra thank you for raising those points. However, I think those are not outdated knowledge. The link you dropped also has the `initializable` interface implemented in some of the samples given. I also believe the `initializable` interface should be implemented if one needs access to other resources like the `URL` and `ResourceBundle`.
For the `Callback`, I got that. I use `Callback` on production code. I only used the `PropertyValueFactory` because the question already had the table columns defined in the `fxml` document.
Thanks anyways for the points.

Comment: FYI - The `initialize()` method does not need to be `public`.

Comment: *”This may not be a problem since the `toString()` method of the `Toggle` would be called”*. This is not true. In this circumstance, if the Person constructor parameter were a `String`, it would be a compile error.

Comment: Thank you @James_D, I have corrected that.